# Disable radio button in Radio List Control in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radiobuttonlist, disabled-input

I have to disable  radio button from the given Radio list control  based on the condition.
The Problem is the Radio button List is auto generated by CMS and id is same on all the list item.
How i can apply "disable" class based on the condition. 
Such as if (some value == am) then show first radio button and disable others two.

```
<div class="fieldset">       
 <div class="radio">
            <label >
                <input id="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0_Sections_9__Fields_3__Value" name="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0.Sections[9].Fields[3].Value" type="radio" value="Morning (8 AM - 1 PM)">
                <span class="disable">Morning (8 AM - 1 PM)</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input id="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0_Sections_9__Fields_3__Value" name="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0.Sections[9].Fields[3].Value" type="radio" value=" Afternoon (1 PM - 5 PM)" aria-invalid="false">
                <span> Afternoon (1 PM - 5 PM)</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input id="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0_Sections_9__Fields_3__Value" name="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0.Sections[9].Fields[3].Value" type="radio" value=" Evening (5 PM - 9 PM)">
                <span> Evening (5 PM - 9 PM)</span>
            </label>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its Generated by  Sitecore Web-form for Marketer. It generate same id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not such a good idea, but you can use jquery to select the radio by the value of the `value` attribute and disable the relevant radio (using the `prop` method):

```js
$('input[type="radio"][value=" Afternoon (1 PM - 5 PM)"]').prop('disabled', true);
$('input[type="radio"][value=" Evening (5 PM - 9 PM)"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fieldset">       
  <div class="radio">
    <label >
      <input id="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0_Sections_9__Fields_3__Value" name="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0.Sections[9].Fields[3].Value" type="radio" value="Morning (8 AM - 1 PM)">
      <span class="disable">Morning (8 AM - 1 PM)</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input id="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0_Sections_9__Fields_3__Value" name="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0.Sections[9].Fields[3].Value" type="radio" value=" Afternoon (1 PM - 5 PM)" aria-invalid="false">
      <span> Afternoon (1 PM - 5 PM)</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input id="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0_Sections_9__Fields_3__Value" name="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0.Sections[9].Fields[3].Value" type="radio" value=" Evening (5 PM - 9 PM)">
      <span> Evening (5 PM - 9 PM)</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var testString="Afternoon (1 PM - 5 PM)";//show only this text control and hide other control

  $.each($('input[type=radio]'),function(i,v){
  if($.trim($(v).val())!=testString)// any condtion you can put here
    {
    $(v).addClass("disable").next().addClass("disable");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.disable
{
 display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fieldset">       
 <div class="radio">
            <label >
                <input id="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0_Sections_9__Fields_3__Value" name="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0.Sections[9].Fields[3].Value" type="radio" value="Morning (8 AM - 1 PM)">
                <span class="">Morning (8 AM - 1 PM)</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input id="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0_Sections_9__Fields_3__Value" name="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0.Sections[9].Fields[3].Value" type="radio" value=" Afternoon (1 PM - 5 PM)" aria-invalid="false">
                <span> Afternoon (1 PM - 5 PM)</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input id="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0_Sections_9__Fields_3__Value" name="wffmd4800a78bba44322993e9ef2a91e0ea0.Sections[9].Fields[3].Value" type="radio" value=" Evening (5 PM - 9 PM)">
                <span> Evening (5 PM - 9 PM)</span>
            </label>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```